# При нажатии изображения оно заркелилось

Tags: php

Помогите, горю, если у кого-нибудь готовое решение что бы при нажатии изображения, оно заркалилось (передовалось методом пост) и наложение сепии?

Comment: Поподробней, пожалуйста, опишите задачу.

Comment: есть картинка, при нажатии на кнопку отзеркалить появлялась отзеркаленная эта же картинка

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример из сети:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("img.jpg");
$x = @imagesx($image);
$y = @imagesy($image);
$des = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $y; $j++) {
        $color = imagecolorat($image, $i, $j);
        imagesetpixel($des, $x - $i - 1, $j, $color );
    }
}

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

@imagejpeg($des);
```

[Взято тут](http://bit.ly/1nJnyF6)

Comment: ну я так понимаю сей код будет работать только с jpeg?

Comment: @нгш, и png и gif (первый кадр) и bmp и еще несколько, смотрите справку: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php и подбирайте нужные себе ф-ции

Comment: кстати предоставленный код не работает))

Comment: @нгш, а посмотреть почему не работает, не хотели?
Вот оригинал http://j290065.myjino.ru/img.jpg а вот то что в коде (я обновил его) в ответе http://j290065.myjino.ru/

Comment: спасибо, я же сказал, что только учусь, я понимаю о чём этот код, но вот редактировать его у меня мозга не хватает, если вам не сложно помогите ещё пож-та с таким вопросом - http://tarasik22.tmweb.ru/index.php/eeeee/1-test/detail/1-car это сайт который делает, там кнопка отзеркалить - т.е. при нажатии она должна передоваться постом в др. файл, и обратно, как поймать переменную я понимаю а вот как её отправить?

Comment: @нгш, а может ну его? Может проще сделать это на стороне пользователя? Вот посмотрите насколько это просто http://jsfiddle.net/F4jXW/

Comment: @jackrv
спасибо, заработало, добавли ещё в код 
 -ms-filter: "FlipH"; 
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
и стало всё красиво работать, вот только такого же решения на сепию не нашёл - пробывал так же через css, но там только последние браузеры работают

Answer (score 0):

а че сложного?? получаете картинку, читаете попиксельно  (координаты и цвет) в другом холсте отзеркаливаетет координаты и ставите цвет - вот и все

Comment: вот это у вас всё так просто, а я ещё только учусь, и для меня это сложно